# How to Image popup when click Angular 7

Tags: angular7

I tried this library. **angular-modal-gallery**. [doc](https://ks89.github.io/angular-modal-gallery-2018.github.io/gettingStarted)

Problem is when popup image, it's showing in small size and initial size also too samall. I want to show image in large size.Similar to this site examples
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Gallery-Popup-jQuery-Fs-Gal/

Please tell me any method to do this.

Here is the code I used in **angular-modal-gallery** library.

html code

```
<ks-modal-gallery  *ngIf="stuf.itemType == 0" [id]="1" [modalImages]="getImage(stuf.itemId)"></ks-modal-gallery>
```

typescript code

```
import { Image } from 'angular-modal-gallery';
images: Image[];
ingleImage: Image[];
getImage(url: string) {
     this.images = [
      new Image(
        0,
        { // modal
          img: this.baseUrl + 'Upload/Photos/' + url + '.jpg',
          extUrl: 'http://www.google.com'
        }
      )];

    return  this.singleImage = [this.images[0]];
}
```